# Ansible define new variable with value from other

Tags: variables, ansible, manipulate

I need some help with Ansible variables.

```yaml
---
- name: create remote ansible account
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: admin
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_pass: mypassword
    ansible_become_pass: mypassword
    publickey: "{{ inputvalue }}"

  vars_files:
    - publickey_file.yml

roles:
  - create account
```

*publickey_file.yml* looks like this:

```yaml
entry1: ssh-rsa AAAAB3....
entry2: ssh-rsa AAAAC3....
```

Specific task in role looks like this:
aml

```
- name: install SSH Key
  authorized_key: 
    user: ansible
    key: '{{ publickey }}'
  become: yes
```

I would like to push a specific public key when specifying a variables with `ansible-playbook`.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```sh
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml myplaybook.yml -e 'inputvalue=entry1'
```

This does not insert the value `"{{ entry1 }}"` but only the word `'entry1'`, so, inserted the key are not correct in module the `authorized_key`.

How can I insert, in `publickey`, the variable value `"{{ entry1 }}"` instead of `'entry1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) in order to find a variable named as the string contained in the variable `inputvalue`:

```yaml
publickey: "{{ lookup('vars', inputvalue) }}"
```